# Please vote more often!

Tags: discussion, voting

Just a reminder to those visiting the site to upvote good content when you see it!

This site will only continue to grow if we encourage good questions/answers and get the users posting them more involved in the site. More upvotes means more users

- with high reputation;
- who can edit posts and tags;
- who can use the review queues;
- who can offer bounties for other questions/answers;
- who receive an Achievement and Reputation Notification on every site, which is likely to encourage a visit, further promoting the above activities.

Further, it helps questions get onto the list of Hot Network Questions, which can attract users from related sites not previously aware of OR.SE. As a more long-term goal, SE also tracks the reputation of users for the purpose of deciding whether a site can graduate or if it stays open.

Revival of [this post](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/vote-early-vote-often): voting is crucial for gaining new users, retaining current users, and showing the SE network that this community is important enough to put resources towards.

<sub>Credits to Tyberius, and for permission to [copy from Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/voting-especially-upvoting-matters).</sub>

Comment: That's a great step towards building this community. I have been doing the same too whenever I am seeing any posts where the OP is trying to express their problem. Will continue to do so. Also, the OR community here has been pretty good! Thank you people!

Comment: @Shibaprasadb Welcome to OR.SE, and thank you for contributing to voting on posts! The community looks forward to any future questions/answers you have.